# как передвинуть поле авторизации, и вообще как двигать целые блоки данных (картинки с текстом, и т.д.)

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href = "оформление.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ставки и информационный портал.</title>
    </head>
<body>
<a class="button-purple">Dota 2</a>
<a class="button-purple">Counter Strike GO </a>
<form>
<div class = "authorization" >
<label for = "имя пользователя">Имя пользователя: </label>
<input autofocus type = "text"  name = "имя пользователя" placeholder = "username" required /><br/>
<label for = "пароль">Пароль:                     </label>
<input type = "password" name = "пароль" placeholder = "password" required /><br/>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

Ставки и события
    Информация Counter Strike: GO
    
'

Comment: Совершенно непонятно о чем речь. Дополните пожалуйста вопрос подробностями.

Comment: Не совсем понятный вопрос...И ты кинул вообще тег который обозначает что ты используешь html5

Comment: Я не понимаю как сюда добавить код к сожалению. Речь идет о том, что я не могу передвинуть поля login и password.